# View fixed at the bottom Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fixed

I'm sorry if someone had asked that question before, I didn't find the same.
I have a view with an image and it has to be always fixed a the bottom in my iOS Swift app. 
Even if I go to another screen it still has to be at the bottom, and it has to be the same view, not different ones for different screens.
Thank you

Comment: can you share code please

Comment: Search for tutorials and info on child view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the root view controller for your app a generic UIViewController.

Add your image view to the bottom of your root view controller

Drag a container view onto that view controller. Make the container view extend down to just above your image view.

Now create a new view controller scene in your storyboard. It can be a navigation view controller if you want a navigation stack, or a tab bar controller, or whatever type you want.

Control-drag from the container view on your root view controller onto your new view controller. Select "embed" in the dialog that appears. You have now created an embed segue, and your root view controller contains a child view controller.

Now, do all your navigation from your child view controller. It will always occupy most, but not all of the screen, and the root view controller will still be visible with the image view at its bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom UIWindow to the bottom of the screen:

Instantiate a UIWindow with a frame (origin and size), and set its `rootViewController` to a UIViewController containing your UIImageView. To show the window, set `isHidden` to `false`. If you don't want the main window to overlap with the custom window, decrease the main window's height by the height of the custom window.

You can do all of this in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in your AppDelegate.

Here is a quick example that I used with an ad banner:

```
window?.frame.size.height -= adBannerHeight
adWindow = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - adBannerHeight, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: adBannerHeight))
adWindow?.rootViewController = AdViewController()
adWindow?.isHidden = false
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create custom view with image to load every screen as fixed view.

```
//CusomeView

import UIKit

class CustomeView: UIView {

var contentView: UIView!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}


}
```

Now you can add this custom View to every viewController where you wants to show in bottom area check below code to load the custom view.

You can also create common method for loading custom view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cv: CustomeView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomeView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CustomeView {
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Hope this help